# HTTP request stream not firing readable when reading fixed sizes

Tags: node.js

I am trying to work with the new Streams API in Node.js, but having troubles when specifying a fixed read buffer size.

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.get('http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k', function (res) {
    res.on('readable', function () {
        var receiveBuffer = res.read(1024);
        console.log(receiveBuffer.length);
    });
});
```

This code will receive a few buffers and then exit.  However, if I add this line after the `console.log()` line:

```
res.read(0);
```

... all is well again.  My program continues to stream as predicted.

Why is this happening?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explained [here](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#consuming-a-readable-stream).

As far as I understand it, by reading only 1024 bytes with each `readable` event, Node is left to assume that you're not interested in the rest of the data that's in the stream buffers, and discards it. Issuing the `read(0)` (in the same event loop iteration) 'resets' this behaviour. I'm not sure why the process exits after reading a couple of 1024-byte buffers though; I can recreate it, but I don't understand it yet :)

If you don't have a specific reason to use the 1024-byte reads, just read the entire buffer for each event:

```
var receiveBuffer = res.read();
```

Or instead of using non-flowing mode, use flowing mode by using the `data/end` events instead:

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.get('http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k', function (res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
    console.log('chunk:', chunk.length);
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    var result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log('final result:', result.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow... that seems to be a very broken API.  Hopefully they clean it up before locking down at 1.x.  Thanks for the info!