# NodeJS: convert pngjs stream to base64

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a PNG object which I created using node-png and according the docs it's a "[readable and writable Stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-png)".

I would like to convert the PNG object to base64 and send it to the client via socket.io where I'll place the string in an image src.

I've tried many things but it seems that it's not trivial to convert a stream into a string.

Note that the data is created inside Node and not from the file system.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is what I did for future readers ([this helped too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310710/http-request-stream-not-firing-readable-when-reading-fixed-sizes)):

```
png.pack();
var chunks = [];
png.on('data', function (chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
  console.log('chunk:', chunk.length);
});
png.on('end', function () {
  var result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  console.log('final result:', result.length);
  io.sockets.emit('image', result.toString('base64'));
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using string concatenation instead of pushing chunks gives you odd results if you're dealing w/ images specifically. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to convert the stream into a string but its readable chunk:

```
stream.on('readable', function() {
  var string = stream.read().toString('base64');

  // send through websocket  
});
```

You can also do this for the complete data running through the stream:

```
var data = '';

stream.on('readable', function() {
  data += stream.read().toString('base64');
});
stream.on('end', function() {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Depends on if the client requires the complete png picture to be available or if it is okay to have single chunks.

However if you are interested how this could look like in an practical example (with the image being uploaded by HTML5 Drag & Drop) you can checkout [messenger](https://github.com/bodokaiser/messenger).